# is there a way to inherit the functions in a module into a class

Tags: python

i have a module with many functions defined in it. Is there a way to inherit all these functions into a class i have in another module.

say i have `module1` with function `func1(), func2()`

I have another module module2 where i have a class

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        .....
    def func3(self):
        ....
```

I want to inherit `func1()` and `func2()` from module1 into class1. So any object of class1 should be able to access these functions.

```
obj1 = class1()
```

I should be able to do `obj1.func1()`

Is there a way to acheive this in python

Comment: `from module1 import class1.func3`

Comment: Functions in a module don't belong to any class, so there's nothing to inherit them from. You can import some or all of them and call them from members of the class defined in module2.

Comment: you can **inherit** only from a subclass. A better term to describe what you want to achieve would be to **map** them to the class. Since the functions in your module don't accept any parameters the question is: Do you want to map them to become static, class or instance methods? It could be achieved with metaclasses, but in the case of the latter two, the functions must accept at least one parameter which should be named `cls` or `self` respectively. Anyway, this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your functions from `module1` to `module2` and then map them from your class:

```
from module1 import func1, func2

class class1(object):
    ...
    def func1(self):
        return func1()

    def func2(self):
        return func2()
```

This is a bit strange, though. If your methods don't receive an instance of the class, why would you use them like that?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
from module1 import func1, func2

class Class1(object):

  def func3(self):
    ...

setattr(Class1, 'func1', func1)
setattr(Class1, 'func2', func2)
```

Be careful when you define func1 and func2 to add self as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to include a few functions from a module - and don't require them to be passed the instance when called - assign them as static methods to the class:

```
from module1 import func1, func2

class Class1(object):
    func1 = staticmethod(func1)
    func2 = staticmethod(func2)
```

If you want to include *all* of the functions, you can override `__getattr__`:

```
import module1

class Class1(object):
    def __getattr_(self, attr):
        try:
            return getattr(module1, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            # catch & re-raise with the class as the 
            # object type in the exception message
            raise AttributeError, 'Class1' object has no attribute '{}'.format(attr)
```